# Kotlin: Generic function as return type?

Tags: function, generics, lambda, kotlin

In Kotlin, is it possible to declare a generic function type as the return type of a function?

What I want to achieve would look like this in Java:

```java
interface Factory {

    static Factory INSTANCE = new FactoryImpl();

    <T> T create(String name, Class<T> type);

}

class PrefixedFactory implements Factory {
    private final String prefix;

    PrefixedFactory(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T create(String name, Class<T> type) {
        return Factory.INSTANCE.create(prefix + name, type);
    }
}
```

(Note that in the example I access the Factory instance using the static field to avoid passing a generic function as a parameter, which would present its own problems in Kotlin).
I would like convert the prefixer to a kotlin function, but it seems to be impossible to declare a generic function as the return type:

```
fun prefixer(prefix: String): <T> (String, KClass<T>) -> T { TODO() }
```

This of course does not compile. It seems to me that this is a limitation compared to Java's functional interfaces. Is there a way to accomplish this, or a workaround?

### (Edit) Clarification

I want the actual result function to be generic. If I do

```
fun <T: Any> prefixer(prefix: String): (String, KClass<T>) -> T { TODO() }
```

as the current answers suggest; I don't get a generic function, instead I get `(String, KClass<Foo>) -> Foo` if I call `prefixer<Foo>("")`. So that function can only be called with `Foo`, while the factory function `prefixer` in that case is generic, the result is not. I hope that clears up the misunderstandings.

My use case is in a Gradle plugin, where I wrote a helper method similar to this one that applies some defaults to each task created:

```
val myPrefix = "..."
val project: Project = <from context>
fun <T: Task> String.task(type: KClass<T>, doConfig: T.() -> Unit) {
  project.tasks.create("$prefix$this", type.java, { it.doConfig() })
}
```

Note that the project comes in as closure. Now I want to reuse that helper in a different plugin, so I would like to create this function using a factory for different project instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible (as far as I know). The technical term for such a type is "higher-kinded type" and very few languages support them, on JVM I only know of Scala.

If someone asked me the same question without having an interface like `Factory`, I'd suggest creating exactly this interface as a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it almost correctly. You only need to define the generic part at the `prefixer` function directly.

```
fun <T: Any> prefixer(prefix: String): (String, KClass<T>) -> T { TODO() }
```

Depending on you actual implementation, you could have a look at the [`reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) keyword.

Comment: The same problem as with @RobCo 's answer applies here - I basically want to return a function equivalent to `fun <T: Any> (String, KClass<T>) -> T`, except I can't specify that as a return type.

Comment: How would you implement a generic function like this? You'd have to store it in a variable which holds the non-generic information. You'd have to cast it from there anyway. Maybe extend a little on what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

The following line does compile:

```
fun <T : Any> prefixer(prefix: String): (String, KClass<T>) -> T = TODO()
```

First, the generic deceleration should be right after the fun keyword.

Then it has has to be declared as type Any. The default is Any? but KClass only takes Any.

Comment: But then the returned function is not generic, it is fixed to whatever `T` is at the call to `prefixer`.

Answer (score 2):

Although I was disappointed to read @Alexey's answer, I found a more streamlined workaround taking advantage of Kotlin's operators. The following makes it look more like a lambda when used:

```
private class Prefixer(private val: String) {
    operator fun <T> invoke(name: String, type: Class<T>): T {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
val createMy = Prefixer("MyPrefix")
val result = createMy("Configuration", Configuration::class.java)
```

Feel free to replace with `KClass` where necessary. I was actually using this for a slightly different purpose.